# Why does changing to a low register in thumb2 increase the cycle count?

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, cortex-m, thumb

I've changed in my thumb2 assembly code all r10 into r4.
As expected the size did shrunk a bit.
But the cycles executed increased. Though there are still the same instructions, just a few now in narrow instead of wide.

Why did that happen?

There are no interrupts used at all, only flash and ram is accessed (within the timed routine).

I've run my code on a Cortex-M4 (STM32F411) with 0 wait states, and with or without prefetch and/or icache. I've measured it with DWT:CYCCNT.
It increased from 1902619 to 1908268 cycles, about 0.2%. (The cycles wary by a few with/-out the icache/prefetch.)

Comment: Is the code short enough that you can share both versions, or can you reproduce the phenomenon with a short example?  It might not be a generic effect, but something specific to what you are doing.

Comment: code alignment of later instructions can matter.  Without a [mcve] or any kind of clue about surrounding code, this is obviously unanswerable.

Comment: Is it possible that it requires more cycles when a 32 bit thumb instruction is not word aligned?
I've aligned all 32bit instructions to word boundary and now it's even faster.

Comment: It seems that word alignment matters for wide branch instructions, they take more cycles otherwise. On the STM32F411 I've tested on.

Comment: "All fetches are word-wide. The number of instructions fetched per word depends on the code running and the alignment of the code in memory."  Read the docs

Comment: So for example if you have 4 thumb2 instructions, and all 4 are aligned it takes 4 fetches, but if they are unaligned it takes 6 fetches.  2 extra fetch cycles which are not assumed to be one clock. Now the STM32 has some flash cache stuff with some trademarked name that you generally cannot defeat, and that will help take that down to one clock per fetch against flash but 2 or more esp if you bump the clock speed up is expected per fetch, execution in the processor does not drive the performance of an MCU.

Comment: There are other cycle eaters as Michael Abrash calls them, that you also need to be aware of and they dont translate from one cortex-m4 to another or one cortex-m to another.  Some cortex-ms the fetch size is compile time optional (when the chip vendor compiles the core).  And despite what the TRM lists as optional and not, there are still some things not documented you can mess with.

Comment: With a pipelined architecture there is no reason to expect the same machine code landing on different alignments will perform the same.

Comment: Please provide the disassembly of the before and after code...with respect to this high and low register (plus surrounding code of course).

Answer (score 3):

Code under test:

```
    ldr r2,[r0]

---- code under test ----
loop:   
    subs r1,#1
    bne loop
---- code under test ----

    ldr r3,[r0]
    subs r0,r2,r3
    bx lr
```

R0 contains points at the systick count register, the code under test is basically measured as closely and repeatably as possible.  Systick is just as good and maybe easier than DWT.

I am running from ram because this is an mcu but more important because it is an STM32 which with perhaps a very few exceptions have a prefetch cache in front of the flash that you cannot disable nor easily defeat, making benchmarking a PITA.

Changing between low registers and high registers

```
add r3,r10,r11
add r3,r3,r4

c:  eb0a 030b   add.w   r3, sl, fp
c:  4423        add r3, r4
```

Basically it is two halfwords vs one.  By changing certain registers in certain instructions can cause the instruction size to change, this instruction size change affects the alignment of the code that follows.

The test code

```
  10:   6802        ldr r2, [r0, #0]

00000012 <loop>:
  12:   3901        subs    r1, #1
  14:   d1fd        bne.n   12 <loop>

  16:   6803        ldr r3, [r0, #0]
  18:   1ad0        subs    r0, r2, r3
  1a:   4770        bx  lr
```

Loop is not aligned on a word boundary (0x12)

The test is run four times with 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x20000, 0x30000 loops (r1=0x10000, ...)

gives

```
0005FFFD 
0005FFFD 
000BFFFD 
0011FFFD
```

So now same machine code, aligned on a word boundary.

```
00000010 <loop>:
  10:   3901        subs    r1, #1
  12:   d1fd        bne.n   10 <loop>

00040001 
00040001 
00080001 
000C0001
```

The machine code matches in each case

```
12: 3901        subs    r1, #1
14: d1fd        bne.n   12 <loop>

10: 3901        subs    r1, #1
12: d1fd        bne.n   10 <loop>
```

Change the alignment by a halfword and the performance changes dramatically

Naturally you should always have the ARM documentation handy whenever doing any ARM assembly language programming:

"All fetches are word-wide. The number of instructions fetched per word depends on the code running and the alignment of the code in memory."

Note the different Cortex-M cores may have different fetch options don't assume because the Cortex-M4 says one thing, the others don't do something different.

For the record the simple example above does not demonstrate a problem in flash.  The STM32 products have a flash cache (has some fancy marketing name and trademark and perhaps patent) that you cannot turn off (in general).

This worked in flash

```
08000032 <loop>:
 8000032:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000036:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 800003a:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 800003e:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000042:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000046:   3901        subs    r1, #1
 8000048:   d1f3        bne.n   8000032 <loop>

00090000 
00090000 
00120000 
001B0000
```

vs

```
08000030 <loop>:
 8000030:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000034:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000038:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 800003c:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000040:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 8000044:   3901        subs    r1, #1
 8000046:   d1f3        bne.n   8000030 <loop>
 
00080000 
00080000 
00100000 
00180000
```

Same machine code, halfword alignment change.  12.5% faster.

Some non-STM32's this kind of work is much easier (in the flash) because they don't have a fancy cache thing and/or rely on ARM's cache which you can enable/disable.